# php mcrypt on cent os 6.5

Tags: centos, php-mcrypt

I have a problem with my php/apache setup on Cent OS 6.5 with php 5.5
I'm using a vagrant box where I installed php-mcrypt and it seems to work on the command line

```
php -r 'echo extension_loaded('mcrypt'), PHP_EOL;'
```

returns 1 (true)

But when I try to use Laravel, it exits with "Mcrypt PHP extension required."

The check with extension_loaded('mcrypt') in start.php returns false

When I create a phpinfo() page, I can only see an mcrypt entry in the "Module authors", but not anywhere else on the page.

When I check my /etc/php.d/ folder, I see that there is a 20-mcrypt.ini file with a reference to mcrypt.so, but this init file is not available in the "Additional .ini files parsed" on the phpinfo() page.

How can I solve this?

EDIT:
it seems that the commandline is using a different php version (5.5.20) compared to the apache server (5.5.16)

I had to update this php version to make it possible to install mcrypt, I used these commands:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

yum -y update php55u
yum -y install php55u-mcrypt
```

This executed without errors, but maybe this was not enough?

Comment: Are you using PHP as apache module? If yes, make sure you have reloaded Apache after installing the mcrypt module.

Comment: yes, I executed "service httpd restart" after installing the mcrypt module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the issue, it was indeed a service that wasn't restarted (as etagenklo said). I restarted the httpd service, but this was not the one that had to be restarted (service php-fpm). It was a vagrant box without documentation so I didn't know that I had to restart this service too